# Excel VBA: No se puede obtener una coincidencia

Tags: excel, vba

Parece que no puedo hacer que funcione en mi laptop y en mi computadora, lo probé en la computadora de un compañero y funcionó perfectamente.

Sigo recibiendo el error mencionado:

> error "No se puede obtener la propiedad Maxifs de la clase WorksheetFunction"

La idea es que busque un valor dependiendo de un criterio que es variable y el rango de búsqueda y criterios también:

```
Sub Difdia(celda As Single) Dim Fi, Fu, Maximo, Fini, Fult As Single

 Fini = venta.Range("ventdia").Row + 1 Fult =
 venta.Range("ventdia").End(xlDown).Row



 Set range1 = venta.Range(venta.Cells(Fini, 1), venta.Cells(celda - 1,
 1)) Set range2 = venta.Range(venta.Cells(Fini, 3), venta.Cells(celda -
 1, 3)) Set crit = venta.Cells(celda, 3)


 venta.Cells(213, 8) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Maxifs(range1,
 range2, crit)



 End Sub
```

Comment: Nota: Esta característica está disponible en Windows o Mac si tiene Office 2019 o si tiene una suscripción a Microsoft 365. Si es un suscriptor deMicrosoft 365, asegúrese de tener la última versión de Office. si no tienes esa versión no te funcionará nunca.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Tal y como indica @Damian, la función MAXIFS solamente está disponible en Excel 2019 o superior. Si tu lap top tiene una versión más antigua (Excel 2016, por ejemplo). nunca funcionará.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vamos por partes.

Lo primero, en tu código no defines bien las variables. Cuando se definen variables, debes especificar siempre qué tipo, o se crearán como `Variant`.

En tu código `Fi, Fu, Maximo, Fini` se declaran como `Variant`. El resto como `Single` porque lo especificaste.

Debería ser `Fi as Single, Fu as Single, Maximo as single, Fini as Single`.

Lo segundo, te falla el código porque estás llamando a una función que no existe en tu versión de Excel.

Antes de que se existiera MAXIFS, se tenía que hacer o matricialmente o con SUMAPRODUCTO y operadores dobles unarios.

Como tú quieres llevarte el valor a una variable en tiempo de ejecución, vamos a descartar hacerlo matricialmente, y usaremos SUMAPRODUCTO combinado con operador doble unario.

> [SUMAPRODUCTO (función
>   SUMAPRODUCTO)](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/sumaproducto-funci%C3%B3n-sumaproducto-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e)
>
> [OPERADOR DOBLE UNARIO](https://es.switch-case.com/3286197)

Como no hay ejemplo de datos, he inventado 1 muy sencillo.

Tengo 2 columnas: en la A alterno los valores `a,b`. Y en la columna B valores del 1 al 6.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la columna E tengo una fórmula que me calcula el máximo valor de B, pero dependiendo de si en A tengo `a` o `b`. Vamos, es como el MAXIFS.

Mi fórmula en la columna E es:

```
=MAX(--($A$1:$A$6=D1)*$B$1:$B$6)
```

Esta fórmula funciona así:

1. `--($A$1:$A$6=D1)` Esta parte, por el operador doble unario, devolverá una matriz de unos y ceros, según cumpla una condición o no (la condición es ser igual a `a`. En este caso, devolverá una matriz tal que así--> `{1;0;1;0;1;0)`
2. `$B$1:$B$6` Esto es un rango con los valores, es decir, una matriz así: `{1;2;3;4;5;6}`
3. `--($A$1:$A$6=D1)*$B$1:$B$6` Multiplicamos ambas matrices, es decir, `{1;0;1;0;1;0) * {1;2;3;4;5;6}` y obtenemos una nueva matriz: `{1;0;3;0;5;0}`
4. MAX devolverá el valor máximo de la matriz obtenida en el paso 3, que es el número 5 para la letra `a`

Esto funciona en cualquier versión de Excel desde 2007 (no sé si en Excel anterior a 2007 funcionaría, nunca lo he probado).

Ahora que ya sabes hacerlo en Excel, hay que pasarlo a VBA. Para guardar el cálculo anterior en una variable, sería:

```
Dim MiResultado As Single

MiResultado = [MAX(--($A$1:$A$6=D1)*$B$1:$B$6)]

Debug.Print MiResultado
```

Y verás que obtengo un 5 también.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Cuando lo tienes ya en una variable, te lo puedes llevar a donde quieras (otra celda por ejemplo)

Ten en cuenta que la parte `[MAX(--($A$1:$A$6=D1)*$B$1:$B$6)]` no deja de ser un texto, es decir, un `String`, así que podrías manipularlo a tu antojo con un bucle e irlo calculando para cada celda, cambiando el criterio si fuera necesario.

Espero que puedas adaptar esto a tus necesidades.

Answer (score 2):

es cierto lo que te comentan con respecto a que la función "Maxifs" no se encuentra en versiones anteriores de Office 2019, pero para tu caso particular puedes usar la siguiente función que no tendría problemas con los demás office, te dejo el código de la función definida por usuario:

```
Public Function MaxSiConjunto(range1 As Range, range2 As Range, crit As Range) As Integer

    Dim C As Range
    Dim Max As Double
    Dim counter As Integer

    Max = 0
    counter = 1

    For Each C In range1
        valor1 = range2.Cells(counter, 1)
        If valor1 = crit.Value Then
            If C.Value > Max Then
                Max = C.Value
            End If
        End If
        counter = counter + 1
    Next C

    MaxSiConjunto = Max
End Function
```

Pega ese código en un módulo y podrás invocar la función tanto en la hoja de Excel, como también en un módulo de VBA. Ten en cuenta que es sólo una alternativa a la función "Maxifs", puesto que esta función ("Maxifs"), soporta hasta 126 criterios, en cambio lo que te ofrezco sólo puede analizar un sólo criterio.

Comment: Funciona perfectamente. Solo una observación: en ningún momento declaras `valor1 `, así que cuando se usa combinado con `Option Explicit` da error. Y luego, creo que tu UDF debería ser `Single` o `Doble` porque siendo `Integer` limitas el valor, aparte de no admitir decimales.

Comment: Gracias por la observación, el código es libre de ser modificado, sólo es un ejemplo para el caso particular de quién formuló la pregunta. saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias efectivamente el problema era que no tenia la versión actualizada de excel y el código ya funciono perfectamente muchas gracias por el apoyo y las alternativas espero pronto apoyar